# Use names of data frames stored in list (within loop construct)

Tags: r, list, loops

I am currently experiencing issues with a loop construct of mine.
I loop over several data frames that are stored in a list.
For each iteration, I would like to extract the name of the data frame to be then used as output name.
I tried the following:

```
df_list<-list(df1, df2, df3)
#Looping across list of data frames ...
#Extract name of data frame:
name<-paste0(as.character(df_list[[i]]), "result")
```

However, this approach extract the complete content of the data frame and uses it as variable name.
I tried several other approaches, but all failed...

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: what does `names(df_list)` return?

Comment: It returns NULL.

Comment: By default, your list of data frames will not have names, you can provide it using `names(df_list) <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tibble::lst()` to create the list.. this function automatically uses the 'name' of the added object as name in the list, so it always returns a named list.

so
`df_list <- tibble::lst( df1, df2, df3 )`